# Is ITaskScheduler supported in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, scheduled-tasks, task, windows-7-x64

Is [`ITaskScheduler`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa381811%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) supported in Windows 7?

I've used the Task Scheduler in Windows XP and Windows Vista to create scheduled tasks.

On Windows 7 the job gets (correctly) created, for example:

```
C:\Windows\Tasks\Foo Test Task.job
```

But the task never runs and doesn't appear in the Task Scheduler UI (Start -> Task Scheduler):

[image]

**Note:** According to MSDN, `ITaskScheduler` is part of the now deprecated **Task Scheduler 1.0 API**. New applications should use [`ITaskService`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa381832%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), part of **Task Scheduler 2.0**.

Since `ITaskScheduler` doesn't work (for me) under Windows 7 (but did work under Windows Vista) I wonder if it's no longer supported (even though the the COM objects exist, the code causes no errors, and it creates the job).

While MSDN doesn't include **Windows 7** in the list of supported OS's for Task Scheduler 1.0, it also doesn't even say that Windows 7 supports Task Scheduler 2.0:

> [Run-Time Requirements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383614%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)
>
> The Task Scheduler requires the
>   following operating systems.
>
> - Task Scheduler 1.0: Client requires
>     Windows Vista, Windows XP, Windows
>     2000 Professional, Windows Me, or
>     Windows 98. Server requires Windows
>     Server 2008, Windows Server 2003 or
>     Windows 2000 Server.
> - Task Scheduler 2.0: Client requires Windows Vista. Server requires Windows Server 2008.

So officially no task scheduler API is supported on Windows 7.

But is `ITaskScheduler` supported on Windows 7?

Is it expected to work?

Judging by the community comments on the [**Task Scheduler** homepage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383614%28v=VS.85%29.aspx), I guess not:

> **Task Scheduler 1.0 under Windows Vista, Windows 7 etc.**
>   Is it really possible to use Task Scheduler 1,0 under Windows Vista and Windows 7? How can it be done?
>
> **Task Scheduler work-around for Win7**
>   I have the same trouble with Win7 Task Scheduler - Creating a simple task to launch a script/program does not work.
>
> I exported my non-working task as well
>   as a working MS task and compared
>   them.  I changed the following
>   parameter in my exported task and
>   re-imported it and now it works: 
>       <UseUnifiedSchedulingEngine>true</UseUnifiedSchedulingEngine>
>
> This work-around is getting me by for
>   now.
>
> Other thoughts: There does not appear
>   to be a Task Scheduler GUI setting to
>   affect this parameter?  The API
>   description implied a setting of false
>   should work, but for some reason it
>   doesn't? It's hard to believe such a
>   fundemental overshight exists; could
>   it be something else with my Win7
>   setup that requires the true setting?
>   I seem to recall the same problem with
>   a fresh Vista install in the past that
>   was mysteriously resolved before I
>   investigated a work-around.  Hmmm... I
>   think I read also that the new
>   scheduling engine associated with the
>   true setting curiously does not
>   support things like monthly
>   scheduling....?
>
> **Task Schedule in Windows 7 fails but
>   works in Windows XP Pro**
>   I have a
>   scheduled task that executes perfectly
>   well in Windows XP Pro but the same
>   task in Windows 7 returns a "0x2"
>   under "Last Run Result". According to
>   the command line command, "net helpmsg
>   2", "0x2" equates to "The system
>   cannot find the file specified."
>
> I can certainly find the file, and the
>   path I use in the Actions tab has been
>   checked, re-checked, double-checked
>   and triple-checked.
>
> I have read countless posts in
>   multiple forums about this issue. I
>   have yet to find a satisfactory
>   answer.
>
> The action that the task is supposed
>   to execute is a .bat file that calls a
>   Perl script. The Perl script writes
>   one each of the following file types,
>   .txt, .csv, and .xml. Execution of the
>   .bat file from the command line works
>   perfectly well; however, once it is
>   put into a Windows 7 scheduled task,
>   it returns 0x2. This same task under
>   Windows XP Pro works like a champ.
>   What is it about Windows 7 tasks that
>   make it so difficult to execute
>   successfully?

Comment: Well, what MS did with the task scheduler in the past few years is not pretty, but the easiest to find out is simply to interrogate COM to find out whether an interface is supported. If it is, then the contract ensures that you can use it as advertised. However, in the past I have had trouble with the task scheduler between various versions of Windows and basically ended up wrapping the functionality I needed into a class that would then hide the ugly details ...

Comment: Every call returns `S_OK`. Like i said, the code works, the calls don't fail, the `*.job` is created - but it never runs, and don't appear in any UI to be able to manually run it. After it's created i can call `taskScheduler.Activate(taskName, ...) to load it, `task.Run` to execute it, and `.EditWorkItem(0, 0)` to show a Task Scheduler properties dialog box of the item. But it never runs, and doesn't appear in Task Scheduler - half zombie API?

Comment: absolutely sounds like a half zombie API :-| ... even scarier that no one at MS feels compelled to reply to the comments there. Sorry I can't be of real help beyond the advice to encapsulate what you need into a class that hides the platform-specific details.

Answer (score 0):

After Vista you need to use the Task Scheduler 2.0 interface instead of 1.0. Partially can handle the w7 the old scheduler app's, but been lot of diffs between.

If you need to create a cross-platform (xp/vista/w7/w8) scheduler, you need to handle the operating system version and the interfaces. Lot of extra work, but better than create one solution with old interface.